# What dependency should I use for ExceptionHandler

Tags: angular, webpack

I'm trying to add ExceptionHandler before bootstrap function. 
And ExceptionHandler can't find dependencies. I tried to add so

```
import {ExceptionHandler} from 'angular2/src/facade/exception_handler';
import {ExceptionHandler} from '@angular/src/facade/exception_handler';
```

Looks like I need to add an apropriate dependency to my package.json.
I think it is not good way to add import as described above. 
I think it should be added so

```
import {ExceptionHandler} from "@angular/facade";
```

But I don't know exactly how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `angular/core` exception handler

```
import {ExceptionHandler} from 'angular2/core';
```

Comment: True. I'm sorry. My IDEA Webstorm usually add imports automaticaly. Thanks :)